# Can I run compiz with specified profile from terminal?

Tags: command-line, ccsm

I am making a personal Desktop Environment and one of the programs I use is compiz. However, I need to execute all my components from a shell script, and every time I launch compiz it runs in its default mode. Is there any way to run Compiz from the terminal while telling it to use a CCSM profile? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RaduRădeanu yes it does, that's what it calls the settings you export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. So far, you can use `ccsm` with only one from the following four options:

- `-h` (`--help`) - show the help message and exit
- `-p PLUGIN` (`--plugin=PLUGIN`) -open `ccsm` to the page of `PLUGIN`. For example:

  ```
  ccsm -p expo
  ```
- `-c CATEGORY` (`--category=CATEGORY`) - open `ccsm` directly to `CATEGORY`. For example:

  ```
  ccsm -c "Window Management"
  ```
- `-v` (`--version`) -display the current version of `ccsm` and exit.

See `man ccsm` to check all of these.

---

Meanwhile, in your script, you can play with a command similar to the following:

```
(ccsm &) && sleep 2 && xdotool key Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Return && sleep 2 && xdotool key Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Tab Return && sleep 2 && xdotool key slash p a t h slash t o slash y o u r underscore c c s m period p r o f i l e Return
```

You only need to adapt it to your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by setting a different HOME environment variable before starting compiz or ccsm.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)